# How to model a five point rating item predicted by multiple variables some of which are factors?

Tags: survey, discrete-data

I have carried a questionnaire, which has a variety of questions in which the responses are given in a rating form (e.g. 1-5, from bad to good). I now would like to test whether the response to question A is affected by several variables, which include some factors (e.g. gender), some continuous (e.g. age) and also some discrete (other 1-5 responses). My first thought was that I should use a GLM, but I am unsure if this is the best for this type of data and which would be the appropriate distribution.

If anyone would have an idea of what is best to do, I would greatly appreciate to know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your dependent/explained/left-hand-side/y variable is ordinal. In that case I would look into ordered logit, generalized ordered logit, or stereotype logistic regression. These are all models that (in different ways) respect the ordered nature of your variable and try to use that to get a parsimonious model. Various good books exist on this topic, as a Stata user I like : http://www.stata.com/bookstore/regression-models-categorical-dependent-variables/index.html

Comment: hi Maarten, thanks for this. You sent me in the right track. I use R normally, so I think the "polr" command from the MASS package will allow me to do an ordered logit as you suggest.